# Duplicate copy activities from REST API to Json files in Storage Lake

Tags: azure, rest, azure-data-factory

I have a set of more than 2000 issues on JIRA, and plan to copy all of those to a JSON file via Azure Data Factory. However, as Jira API only allows 100 issues per API link, i need to create multiple API links on dataset
(e.g: https://xxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/searchjql=order%20by%20created%20DESC&startAt=0&maxResults=100
https://xxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/searchjql=order%20by%20created%20DESC&startAt=101&maxResults=100
https://xxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/searchjql=order%20by%20created%20DESC&startAt=201&maxResults=100)

This is time-consuming and don't work out in the future when my request can be up to 4000.
If you know whether there's any ways to duplicate the copy activities, so that i just need to use one link with parameter (at "startAt") and can copy the data for the total 2000 requests, please help me
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using an Until or a Foreach activity to loop through the API call? So you create only API 1 activity with your start and max as parameters. Then loop through this incrementing both by 100 each time for the required number of times.

Comment: Hi i thought of it but don't know how to do. Plus, how do i stop the loop (e.g: when startAt < total issues. How to translate it into Data factory's language?

Comment: Do you get the total issues in the response from your API calls? If yes, then you can use that. Else how do you know that you have retrieved all the issues? If you use an Until activity you can set it to continue until the maxresults crosses the total issues retrieved from your call. You will need 2 variables to store the startat and maxresults parameters and pass this to the API call for each iteration.  There's plenty of documentation on using Until activity on the net. Please update the question with what you've tried.

Comment: I have Total issues in API. The problem is it changes daily and we need to find ways to retrieve value of total issues in API calls to pipeline and compare it with maxresults as you said until maxresult cross total issues.

Answer (score 0):

Is there no parameter for start date in your API link?

if you have one, you can use databricks and do a code like this. In my example it would be sys_created_on

```
from datetime import datetime  
from datetime import timedelta  

#starting date is late 2019
curr = datetime.now()
start = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=-500)  ##Whichever date you want to start from


base_url = https://xxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/searchjql=order%20by%20created%20DESC&sys_created_on="

#the loop iterates over a period of 5 days
while start<=curr:
  end = start+ timedelta(days=5)
  url = base_url+str(start)+"^sys_created_on<="+str(end)
  #print(url)
  a = requests.get(url, auth=('****', key))
  c = a.json()
  str_date = start.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
  str_date = str(str_date)
  with open('/dbfs/mnt/****/bronze/****/Jirra_'+str_date[:8]+'.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(c, outfile)
  start = end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can do this.

1. Your ADF can trigger an azure function which will loop through all the API calls, bundle the data together and write into a storage. You can refer to @Piccinin1992's response for the code or use your own.
2. You can do this using a webactivity and refer to the totalissues from the output of the webactivity. You will need to loop through this using an Until loop activity.

First add 3 variables in your pipeline.
[image: Add 3 variables in your pipeline]

Your webactivity url will be a concat of the api url with the startat variable as shown. The maxresults can be hardcoded since these will always be 100.

```
@concat('https://anunetfunc.azurewebsites.net/api/PaginatedAPI?startat=',variables('startat'),'&maxresults=100')
```

[image]

Now you need to set the tempvariable to @variables('startat'). This is because ADF dynamic content does allow you to include the variable that you are setting.

[image]

Next set the startat to temp+100. This is for the next page read.

```
@string(add(int(variables('tempvariable')),100))
```

[image]

Lastly, set the total issues variable to the totalissues from the output of the 1st webactivity.

```
@string(activity('Web1').output.totalissues)
```

[image]

With this, the loop will execute only as many times to fetch all the issues. This is just a skeleton to show you how to do this. You still need to add activities to either bunch up all the issues before writing into storage or write separate files for each API call.

Comment: Hi Anupam, Thank you for the guidance. The loop is running well. However, i encounter another problem with Copy activity. Every time a new set of API data copied to the JSON files, it automatically deleted data from previous loading, at the end i only got result from latest loading only. Do you have any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Add a date time stamp to the file name. Using dynamic content you can add a date function utcnow. See this for an example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#complex-expression-example

Comment: Hi @Nam Nguyen, Did my response answer your question? If so, please mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: hi @anupam, sorry for late response, the steps you mention work well, but i still don't understand how can we write everything to json?

Comment: You can refer to this link for some tips https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lSLnffz3_1M